# Ubuntu How to change welcome message

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

All,

I am using Ubuntu OS in my AWS EC2 instance. My previous developer has created some custom messages once we SSHed into the Instance (Attached). But I would like to change it. Googled extensively, but no luck. Can someone help?[Text I want to change is "Live 1A"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV3Pd.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the file `/etc/motd`

`motd` stands for `Message Of The Day`

**MOTD(5) - Linux Programmer's Manual**

> NAME
>          motd - message of the day
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          The contents of /etc/motd are displayed by login(1) after a successful login but just before it executes the login shell.
>
> The abbreviation "motd" stands for "message of the day", and this file has been traditionally used for exactly that (it requires
>   much less disk space than mail to all users).

Comment: This could also be coming from a script inside `/etc/update-motd.d`.

Comment: Hi, The file '/etc/motd' doesn't exist in my Instance. However I can see the file '/etc/update-motd.d/00-header' and I changed the Text and saved. Loggedout and login again. But still can see the old message. The new message i edited is still there. Not sure where the Welcome message coming from.

Comment: Is there any way/logs to track what are the files are called when I login Ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry it is working now when I change the file "/etc/update-motd.d/00-header". It took some time to sync may be. Thanks helloV and Michael.